# Creating lag values for a given set of days

Tags: date, stata, lag

so I have certain dates for each ticker In my data, for example:

| ticker | day | indicator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 21.04.2023 | 4.42 |
| AAPL | 22.04.2023 | 2.22 |
| AAPL | 23.04.2023 | 1.42 |
| AAPL | 27.04.2023 | 7.42 |
| AAPL | 28.04.2023 | 8.42 |
| AAPL | 31.04.2023 | 10.42 |
| GOOGL | 21.04.2023 | 2.42 |
| GOOGL | 22.04.2023 | 3.42 |
| GOOGL | 25.04.2023 | 10.42 |
| GOOGL | 27.04.2023 | 6.42 |

I'm trying to create a lag variable on my custom dates. so it will look like this:

| ticker | day | indicator | lag_indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 21.04.2023 | 4.42 | . |
| AAPL | 22.04.2023 | 2.22 | 4.42 |
| AAPL | 23.04.2023 | 1.42 | 2.22 |
| AAPL | 27.04.2023 | 7.42 | 1.42 |
| AAPL | 28.04.2023 | 8.42 | 7.42 |
| AAPL | 30.04.2023 | 10.42 | 8.42 |
| GOOGL | 21.04.2023 | 2.42 | . |
| GOOGL | 22.04.2023 | 3.42 | 2.42 |
| GOOGL | 25.04.2023 | 10.42 | 3.42 |
| GOOGL | 27.04.2023 | 6.42 | 6.42 |

I tried using stata business calendar with:

```
// create Nasdaq calander 
bcal create nasdaq, from(date_var) 
gen bizdate = bofd("nasdaq",date_var)
bcal load nasdaq
format %tbnasdaq bizdate


xtset ticker_encoded bizdate
```

But it didn't seem to work, As say 30.04.2023 and 27.04.2023 doesn't have any lag values.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I know almost nothing about business calendars, but one of your dates is 31 April 2023. There was no such date. April only has 30 days.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not my real data, just an example of what I wanted to do

Comment: Well, real data or not, 31 April 2023 won't be useful. What else "didn't seem to work"? There is no detail to address in your question. Missing values for the first date in each panel are to be expected.

Comment: Again, this is what I want to get. the problem is I don't get this result at 31.04 (lets say 30.04) and 27.04 gets missing data instead. I changed the 31 of April to 30 to be clearer :)

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example (Google for fuller details) that sets up data and shows all steps. So you include full code and show what is wrong.

Comment: My guess is that with nothing else said, `bcal` identifies weekdays and weekends and so expects runs of 5 days with data and 2 days without. You have a bigger gap, and more gaps, than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used `bcal`. If you do not need to use that tool, here is a reproducible example to get the output you want.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str5 ticker str10 day float indicator
"AAPL"  "21.04.2023"  4.42
"AAPL"  "22.04.2023"  2.22
"AAPL"  "23.04.2023"  1.42
"AAPL"  "27.04.2023"  7.42
"AAPL"  "28.04.2023"  8.42
"AAPL"  "30.04.2023" 10.42
"GOOGL" "21.04.2023"  2.42
"GOOGL" "22.04.2023"  3.42
"GOOGL" "25.04.2023" 10.42
"GOOGL" "27.04.2023"  6.42
end

* Read the dates into Stata date format
gen day2 = date(day, "DMY")
format day2 %d

* day2 sorts correctly such that "17.04.2023" is not sorted before "2.04.2023"
* as any string starting with 1 is sorted before any string starting with 2,
* no matter what the string represents
sort ticker day2

* Get indicator from previsous row ([_n-1]) if ticker is same on previous row
gen lag_indicator = indicator[_n-1] if ticker == ticker[_n-1]
```

Comment: I am sympathetic to this approach but if it is used it seems important to keep track of `gen gap : day2 - day2[_n-1] if ticker == ticker[_n-1]` Else gaps of 4 or more days are treated the same way as gaps of 1 day.

Comment: Sure, but not sure from OP if it matters to keep tracks on the length of the gap.

Comment: This is more substantive or statistical than Stata-based. In my own field I wouldn't be happy with ignoring exact time gaps at any level from u/g Dissertation through PhD thesis to papers being reviewed for publications. Stock price analysis I leave to people in that field.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a forum for programming question, and I answered the question on how to generate the the desired outcome as presented by OP using programming in Stata.

Comment: Absolutely. That is why this small discussion is in comments and marginal to the thread -- just crucial for the OP's research.

Comment: It worked thanks! I just needed to use: 
by ticker: gen lag_indicator = indicator[_n-1]
because your code gave me "weights not allowed" error.

Comment: I can't see any reason why the code in the answer should not work unless you inserted space(s) before the subscript(s).